# Олимпиадная задача 9 класс, структуры данных

Tags: c++, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Пожалуйста, помогите решить задачу! Цель - найти эффективное решение следующей проблемы: нужно создать структуру с парами ключ-значение (ключ не превосходит 10^9) так, чтобы

1. работал метод push(key, value), отвечающий за создание пары ключ-значение, если такого ключа ещё не было, либо за увеличению ключа на значение value, если такой ключ уже был; известно, что value не превосходит 500;
2. можно было в любой момент времени быстро получить 5 ключей с максимальными значениями по ним, пропуская первые K ключей с максимальными значениями (например, выдать 5 максимальных ключей, пропуская 10 первых, значение K в рамках задачи непостоянно, может меняться от запроса к запросу).

Я пытался решить задачу, но мои решения были слишком тривиальными и неэффективными по времени.

Мне кажется, здесь нужно использовать какое-то дерево, возможно, префиксное, но додуматься до красивого решения не получается. При этом важно, что **решение этой задачи подразумевает отказ от использования встроенных хеш-таблиц, словарей, списков, прочих структур "сложнее массива"**.

Comment: думаю, что Вам бы стоило добавить свое решение, хоть какое кривое оно не было. Иначе тут точно заминусуют вопрос и закроют.

Comment: Смотрите как устроен сортированный словарь (или сортированная хеш таблица), вам он походу и нужен

Comment: В с++ eсть orderet_set который позволяет получать значение по границе, у него немаленькая константа, но он встроен и самому его писать не нужно, да и буквально использовать пару методов не так сложно
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordered-set-gnu-c-pbds/

Answer (score 1):

Строим две дерамиды (treap, декартово дерево).

Одна A размером K с инверсным приоритетом - т.е. у неё на макушке минимум.

Другая B - с оставшимися элементами с максимумом на верхушке.

Ключ позволяет искать в любой дерамиде. Если элемент при увеличении value получает значение больше, чем минимум A - передвигаем этот минимум в B, а элемент вставляем в А.

Таким образом, K наибольших ключей всё время лежат в A, а 5 следующих максимумов при необходимости снимаем с верхушки B.

(может быть, даже отдельное хранилище для этой пятёрки завести?)